# Using PHPMailer and my email won't send without var_dump

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have an email set up to send using PHPMailer. It sends fine as is, however, I want to redirect the user to a page after the script completes. So far it just says bool(true) when completed. Here is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$dName = $_POST['dName'] ;
$dAddress = $_POST['dAddress'] ;
$phone = $_POST['phone'] ;
$cName = $_POST['cName'] ;
$cEmail = $_POST['cEmail'] ;
$departure = $_POST['departure'] ;
$rooms = $_POST['rooms'] ;
$attendee1 = $_POST['attendee1'] ;
$attendee2 = $_POST['attendee2'] ;
$transportation = $_POST['transportation'] ;
$file = $_POST['uploaded_file'] ;
$requests = $_POST['requests'] ;

require_once 'libs/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;


if (isset($_FILES['uploaded_file']) &&
    $_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'],
                     $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
}

$mail->From = 'me@example.com';
$mail->FromName = '20th Registration';
$mail->addReplyTo('reply@example.com', 'Reply TO');
$mail->addAddress('send@example.com', 'Sending TO');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com', 'HIDING');



$mail->Subject = 'Fort Wayne Dealer Registration';
$mail->Body =  '<strong>Dealer Name: </strong>' . $dName . '<br/>
         <strong>Dealer Address: </strong>' . $dAddress . '<br/>
         <strong>Phone Number: </strong>' . $phone . '<br/>
         <strong>Contact Person: </strong>' . $cName . '<br/>
         <strong>Contact Email: </strong>' . $cEmail . '<br/>
         <strong>Departure Day: </strong>' . $departure . '<br/>
         <strong>Number of Rooms: </strong>' . $rooms . '<br/>
         <strong>Attendee 1: </strong>' . $attendee1 . '<br/>
         <strong>Attendee 2: </strong>' . $attendee2 . '<br/>
         <strong>Transportation: </strong>' . $transportation . '<br/>
         <strong>Special Requests: </strong>' . $requests . '<br/>';

$mail->AltBody = 'This is the alt body of the email';

var_dump($mail->send());
```

The problem is this will NOT send if I remove var_dump($mail->send());
I would like to use:

```
    if ($mail->Send()) {
echo "worked";
} else {        
    echo "failed: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: capital S in send...

Comment: Thanks for your help. I removed the var_dump line and replaced it with: 

    if ($mail->send()){
    echo "worked";
    } else {
        echo "failed: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }

It still will not send the message.

Comment: you get a blank page... you can't get a blank page unless something crashes... Are you receiving an email?

Comment: Also... have you tried putting an echo AFTER all of that / a var_dump AFTER the attempt to send?

Comment: If this is all the code you have, then there is a syntax error you are missing an ending curly brace in the first if statement... Fyi, the answer below is uninformed, variable names is case-sensitive, functions is NOT, though its best practice to use correct casing on functions.

Comment: @ScottForbes Thanks for the secondary note. I didn't think it mattered, but if I ever come across something like this I'll make sure to do as you mentioned!

Comment: @EJTH didn't know that.. But I think you're right either way.

Comment: @EJTH That ending curly brace was it. Thanks to everyone taking a look at this. I'm really not the best at PHP, so all the pointers really help.